# Moving on from a simple IRC server to some other technology

Tags: php, ajax, rest, push, ape

I would like some opinions about one project.
Sorry my english, is not my natural language.

My current setup:

> Arduino -> IRC SERVER <-> Clients (PHP and custom software)

1 - Arduinos sends a special crafted string to the IRC server.
2 - IRC server has one channel per group of Arduinos.
3 - On every channel there's a bot, catching all the strings sent, and saving them on a SQL database.
4 - I have a cron job, that moves the raw data from the 1st SQL table to another one, with data already parsed, pretty and nice.
5 - Clients, who may use PHP web based site, or a custom software connect to the server.
6 - If they need realtime data, the IRC server is choosen, a command is sent to the Arduino, and this, sends the string either to channel AND to the operator. Otherwise, they get the data from the 2nd SQL table with a simple query date based.
7 - Data is sent with 1 second interval (NEEDED)
8 - This was a quick and dirty hack to get things done.

Now... I need to move from this arcaic system and get things done in the right way.
I have a few notions of APE (Ajax Push Engine), Comet, REST, etc...
The "almost real-time" is a must, so, my guess would be AJAX, right?!
But, what would you use in a situation like this? What would be the most efficient way to have this upgraded? 
My limitation is on the side of Arduino, with the GPRS module, I can only send and receive simple ASCII strings.
Please, Arduino haters, this is not an Arduino doubt/question, forget I even mention it.
This is a simple call for help/ideas about what technology is more efficient to this project?
BTW... I like KISS principle and simple modules, so that debuging won't take more time than the project itself :)
Thanks to all.

Comment: So you want to remove IRC from the chain, but still keep a near-realtime web application?

Comment: Right :) Although I like the simple way IRC works, I've been reading and testing RESTfull interfaces, noSQL stuff, etc, and feel kinda old, lol. And need to keep it simple and fast, the more nodes I have, more lag on IRC and resources are being used.